# How well do Gauss-Legendre quadrature methods fare on "fractal" functions?

Tags: fractals, differential-calculus, quadrature, mandelbrot-set

**The context**

I'm making your tipical Mandelbrot set viewer, and I have a function $f: ℂ → ℕ$ that counts how many iterations of
$$
z_0 = 0 \\
z_{i+1} = z_i^2 + c
$$
it takes for a particular point $c$ before $|z_i| > 2$. Displaying $f(c)$ according to some colourmap generates the typical Mandelbrot set images.

**The problem**

I thought about doing some anti-aliasing by sampling multiple points within each pixel and taking the average. This is a numerical approximation of the mean value of $f$ in the area of the pixel, i.e. a numerical quadrature.

My limited math knowledge is in the Finite Element Method, this led me to think: What if I used Gauss-Legendre quadrature?

**My questions**

- What would you call this type of functions?
- Would Gauss-Legendre quadrature be more accurate than averaging uniformly-spaced points?
- Is there any quadrature method that works well for this type of function?